# error: Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFireDatabase' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using angular 6, "firebase": "^5.5.8", "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0".

I want to deploy a list of my data, but this error appears in the browser console:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFireDatabase' imported by the
>   module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

```
          import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
      import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
      import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
      import {routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';
      import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
      import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
      import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
      import { tempFirebaseRepo } from './Repository/tempFirebase';
      import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';



      //componentes
      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
      import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
      import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
      import { SettingsComponent } from './components/settings/settings.component';
      import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
      import { DataComponent } from './components/menu/data/data.component';
      import { InformeMesComponent } from './components/menu/informe/informe-mes/informe-mes.component';


      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          HeaderComponent,
          FooterComponent,
          SettingsComponent,
          MenuComponent,
          DataComponent,
          InformeMesComponent,
          AngularFireDatabase
        ],
        imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
          BrowserModule,
          ChartsModule,
          routing,
          AngularFirestoreModule,
          AngularFireDatabase,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

        ],
        providers: [
          appRoutingProviders,
          tempFirebaseRepo
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import only module to AppModule & No need to declare firebaseDatabase in AppModule

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
  import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
  import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
  import {routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';
  import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
  import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
  import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
  import { tempFirebaseRepo } from './Repository/tempFirebase';
  import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      HeaderComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      SettingsComponent,
      MenuComponent,
      DataComponent,
      InformeMesComponent
      // Removed
    ],
    imports: [
      HttpClientModule,
      BrowserModule,
      ChartsModule,
      routing,
      AngularFirestoreModule,
      AngularFireDatabaseModule,
      AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

    ],
    providers: [
      appRoutingProviders,
      tempFirebaseRepo
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thanks man, my problem was that i don't found this path "import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';".....it is in all documentations , but the path doesn't were in anyplace, thank you very mach

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your imports to replace **`AngularFireDatabase`** with **`AngularFireDatabaseModule`**:

```
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireDatabaseModule 
  ],
```

and remove AngularFireDatabase from your module imports:

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";
```

AngularFireDatabase should be imported in the component only.